# Web proxies enabled by default is preventing the internet from working

Tags: network, system-settings, web-browser, proxy

I am unable to use the internet with any browsers on my machine because somehow I have got web proxies enabled as shown below in the screenshot - I can turn these off easily but when I reboot both options are enabled again. How do I turn off the web proxies so that they aren't enabled when the mac is booted up?

I am using Monterey 12.1
[image]

P.S I see these options enabled for both WIFI & Ethernet settings within my Network preferences

Comment: It seems that proxy is enabled by some tool. So check the activity monitor to see which app is using port 3545 and then maybe you delete that config from var.